# Surprise frontend requirement after splitting backend into 2 projects

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I had 2 projects in my solution. One WPF frontend and one C# library backend. This worked fine for month, but now I decided that a part of the backend has become complicated enough that I would split it off into it's own, third project.

So now I have 3 projects: 1 with most of the backend code that depends on nothing, 1 other backend code that depends on the first for interfaces, and 1 frontend that depends on the other 2 projects.

There were some namespace changes that I had to fix throughout the code, but else it's a straight forward change. Or so I would think. Because now my frontend suddenly has a requirement for `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors` that was not there before I split the projects (the error tells me it's required for the Xaml triggers that worked fine before).

I tried around adding references to the backend projects thinking that they may be required for some inheritance reason, but that didn't change anything. Only when I imported the Microsoft.Xaml.Behavior.WPF Nuget package to the frontend was the reference resolved.

The weird thing is that I have 0 frontend changes. I can check out the previous commit and the requirement is gone. All that is changes for the frontend are some namespaces and the added reference to the new project.

Where does the requirement suddenly come from?

Comment: Your previous commit works without that nuget and what you have now does not. Either you changed something or dark magic is at work. I should think if you search your new xaml, somewhere you now have an xmlns: “http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors“ ?

Comment: I walked through ever line change in sourcetree, there is no changes to any xaml's, or xaml.cs's. All changes in the frontend are the reference in the project, and the namespace changes in the viewmodels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft dropped support for `System.Windows.Interactivity` & `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` in `.NET 4.8`. The functionality in these assemblies was replaced with a NuGet package: `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`.

Most likely, you recently moved to `.NET 4.8`.

Referencing the NuGet package: `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` was the right course of action.

Here's a blog post that talks about the issue:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/

Comment: This can explain the strange behaviour, but not really why it only came up after the project split, and the not the previous work in the last month.
I guess I'll still mark it as the answer in lieu of a better answer.